# Accessing and crawling the file-system in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

How do I interact with the file system in SWI-Prolog?

I want to do something like this. Write some predicates which match files (either names, or open them up and match contents). But then use Prolog to drive this system so I can do queries and make inferences across the whole thing.

I'm assuming I either need to slurp data about the whole file tree in, in advance. Or I can dynamically generate a "crawl" through the file system inside some recursive predicates.

But I can't find any examples or tutorials that do more than just open, close, read and write a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently a nice predicate has been introduced, [directory_member](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=directory_member/3)/3. It's exactly what you need to make queries about the file structure:

```erlang
?- directory_member('/home/carlo/swipl-devel',Entry,[recursive(true)]).
Entry = '/home/carlo/swipl-devel/INSTALL' ;
Entry = '/home/carlo/swipl-devel/bench' ;
...
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks good. But is it new? I'm using 64 bits, version 7.6.4 (I'm on Ubuntu, and this is the standard that came with it). I tried use_module(library(filesex)). which said true. But I get ERROR: Undefined procedure: directory_member/3 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: @interstar You should upgrade. See [Installing from PPA (Ubuntu Personal Package Archive)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/build/PPA.html)